# On a particular day let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the number of boys born

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

On a particular day let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the number of boys born before the first girl is born in hospitals $1,2,3$ respectively.If the observations are $X_1=0$ ,$X_2=3$ and $X_3=2$, find the most powerful test to test the null hypothesis that a girl and a boy are equally likely to be born against the alternative that a girl is less likely to be born than a boy.

My try:
Let $p$ be the probability of a boy being born.
We need to test the hypothesis $p=\frac{1}{2}$ against $p>\frac{1}{2}$
Now we know that $X_1,X_2,X_3 \sim $ Geometric$(p)$.But I cannot frame the most powerful test in this case on the basis of the observed values.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the likelihood ratio procedure. As $X_i$ are a sample from $\sf{Ge}(p)$ with $p$ unknown, we form the hypotheses $$H_0:p=\frac12,\quad H_1:p=p_1>\frac12.$$ Then the likelihood ratio is $$\frac{f(x\mid p_1)}{f(x\mid p)}=\frac{p_1^n}{(1/2)^n}\left(\frac{1-p_1}{1-1/2}\right)^{\sum X_i-n}>k$$ for some $k\in\Bbb R$. Letting $k'=k^{1/n}$, we get $$2p_1[2(1-p_1)]^{\bar X-1}>k'$$ and as $\bar X$ increases, the LHS decreases since $2(1-p_1)<1$. Thus we choose $c$ such that $P(\bar X<c\mid H_0)=\alpha$ and note that $\sum X_i$ follows a $\sf{NegBin(n,p)}$ distribution. It is possible to [approximate this](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/ApproximationstotheNegativeBinomialdistribution.php) with a Normal distribution, but don't expect it to work too nicely as transformations from a discontinuous function to a continuous one are usually quite complicated.

Comment: But I cannot understand why the observed values of $X_1=0,X_2=3,X_3=2$ are given? Don't they affect the likelihood function anyway?

Comment: @LegendKiller Once you get your distribution and the most powerful test you can plug in $\sf{n=3}$ and the observed $\sf{X_i}$ for $\sf{i=1,2,3}$ to get your test statistic.